# Django: How to pass variable on form submit

Tags: python, django, forms

I have a django 1.6.11 form (views.py):

```
def posneg_nlp(request):
sys_project_name = request.GET.get('project', 'graph') # here oll is ok, it can get correct project value
success = False
monitoring_words = ''
pos_features = ''
neg_features = ''
date_saved = datetime(2015, 7, 29)

print('posneg_nlp form')
print("posneg_nlp request.GET.get('sys_project_name', 'graph')", request.GET.get('project', 'graph'))

if request.method == 'POST':
    posnegnlp_form = PosnegnlpForm(request.POST)
    if posnegnlp_form.is_valid():
        print('posneg_nlp form is_valid')
        success = True
        sys_project_name = sys_project_name
        # here it cannot get project value, it replaced with default:
        print("posneg_nlp form is_valid request.GET.get('sys_project_name', 'graph')", request.GET.get('project', 'graph')) 
        print("sys_project_name ", sys_project_name)
        monitoring_words = posnegnlp_form.cleaned_data['monitoring_words']
        pos_features = posnegnlp_form.cleaned_data['pos_features']
        neg_features = posnegnlp_form.cleaned_data['neg_features']
        print('pos_features:', pos_features, 'neg_features:', neg_features)

        posneg_nlp_filter(sys_project_name, pos_features, neg_features, db_collection=Vkwallpost)
        #get_likes_wallposts_by_owner_id(typeobject='post', owner_id=None, item_id=None, filter_posts='likes')


else:
    posnegnlp_form = PosnegnlpForm()
    success = False

ctx = {'posnegnlp_form': posnegnlp_form, 'sys_project_name': sys_project_name, 'monitoring_words': monitoring_words,
       'pos_features': pos_features, 'neg_features': neg_features, 'success': success}
return render_to_response('choose_nlp_filter.html', ctx, context_instance = RequestContext(request))
```

This is the second form among two. From first form i pass a variable **sys_project_name** to this form via template:

```
                                <div class="rowSubmit">
                                <a style="outline: medium none;" hidefocus="true" href="{{ DOMAIN_URL }}/post/choose_nlp_filter/?project={{ sys_project_name }}" class="btn btn-right"><span class="gradient">К шагу 2. Выбор фильтров&nbsp;</span></a>

                            </div>
```

When i print current value of **sys_project_name** in form function **posneg_nlp(request)** above it shows correct value **request.GET.get('project', 'graph')** equal to graph2 (happens on form render).
But after that after **if posnegnlp_form.is_valid():** it stops to see it and **request.GET.get('project', 'graph')** shows value in case it not found, equal to "graph".

So, how to pass variable and dont allow to rewrite it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first case, the view is responding to an http GET request, so request.GET contains your project parameter. When the form is submitted, now the view is responsing to an http POST request, and request.POST contains the form data.  In the latter case, if you want request.GET to still contain the 'project' parameter, then you can pass it via the form action parameter in your form tag:

form action="/some/url/?project={{ sys_project_name }}"